# WCF self hosted service. system requirements

Tags: c#, wcf

What are the minimum system requirements needed for WCF self hosted service to work?
My client application needs 2 way communication with the server and it will get deployed in systems having OS' XP, Vista, Windows 7. Is it mandatory to have IIS installed in the target PC to make self hosted services work or Is the only requirement is the need of .net 4.0 present in the system?

My application is going to be deployed on thousands of system which may have variety of configuration. In this scenario, Is self hosted service a good solution?

Comment: @ie.yes.HTTP communication is required

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [this sample](http://wcftutorial.net/WCF-Self-Hosting.aspx), ISS (or other HTTP server) is not required.

Answer (score 0):

As the sentence says "WCF self hosted service" doesn't need IIS but it needs the windows feature. WCF is the evolution of the legacy marshall class objects. Today people use REST services to send data through a TOKEN. WCF is focused on desktop applications instead.